# Inlinks and outlinks for a Wikipedia page in python

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I am using the Wikipedia API for python to get page links as follows:

```
import wikipedia
ny = wikipedia.page(wikipedia.search("Barack Obama")[0])
print ny.links
```

This `ny.links` provides all the links (inlinks and outlinks together), but I need them separately. Could anyone please help me finding some means to achieve this using the same API or some other APIs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [wikipedia-api](https://wikipedia-api.readthedocs.io) to get information about inlinks with property [backlinks](https://wikipedia-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wikipediaapi/api.html#wikipediaapi.WikipediaPage.backlinks) and outlinks with property [links](https://wikipedia-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wikipediaapi/api.html#wikipediaapi.WikipediaPage.links).

Code rewritten with Wikipedia-API would look like this:

```
import wikipediaapi
wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
obama = wiki.page("Barack Obama")

# does it exists?
repr(obama.exists())

# show basic info
repr(obama)
# > 'Barack Obama (id: 534366, ns: 0)'

# inlinks
repr(obama.backlinks)
len(obama.backlinks)
# > 28323

# outlinks
repr(obama.links)
len(obama.links)
# > 2138
```